# Force closure of the popup on telegram “Open this link?”

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

When i use html formatting in a post and i create a link, Telegram show a popup **before** open the link. There is a script or something that force closure of the popup and open the link immediatly?

I don't want insert the link **without HTML**.

[image: popup telegram]

Answer (score 2):

I press the enter key down(which I duplicated/remapped to the CapsLock key with Autohotkey) before I click a link. It worked easy & fortunate that there are no weird things will be triggered in the whole process.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution is not good. I need a solution on backend, before that the user click on the link.

Comment: It also works for InlineKeyboardButton(url='some url'). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are no ways to close this popup. Telegram shows this for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you send the full URL, Telegram won't show this message.